# check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '( -

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm just getting into MySQL and I made this column named Name-Player, and it gives me this error. "check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '( -"

I've tried changing the name of it in MySQL workbench but it doesn't update, also tried in MySQL Shell, but it just gives me the same error.

No Code.

Expecting to change the name of it, hoping it will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That column name contains a dash, which is a special character in MySQL.

If you want to keep it like that, you would need to quote this identifier by surrounding it with backticks, each and every time you use it.

A probably better option would be to rename the column to something that does not contain special characters:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE `Name-Player` `my_new_name` <my_datatype>;
```

... where `<my_datatype>` stands for the datatype (and lenght) of your column.

Comment: How can I rename it? I tried the normal method but it just gives me this error.

Comment: @Destinations: answer updated with a query to rename the column.